# Can we say "in common sense way"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

"To understand this principle in common-sense way...." I heard a German teacher using "common-sense" this way, I think it is a little bit odd. Suppose I want to retain his idea, and modify the sentence, how should I say. "To understand XX from the perspective of common-sense"; "To understand XX from the point of view of common-sense"?

I think "from the perspective of an Asian/.." is good, as long as it is of people, "from the perspective of.." will be fine. Also, suppose man have normally different ways of viewing things, they might feel, argue, contemplate. These can be perspectives. So we can also say "from perspective of reason, psychology, motivation..." Psychology, motivation.. are immanate attibute of men. So, either from the perspective of people, or from the perspective of their common ways to know things.

Therefore I think "To understand XX from the perspective of common-sense" is odd as well. Maybe we should say "to understand it by common-sense, with common-sense"?

Answer (score 0):

*Perspective* of common-sense sounds odd, if not wrong.

I'd say, 'to understand it **using** common sense'.